# context is undefined after passing it to template

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Why is rowData undefined inside extensiontemplate? It is ok before passing it to the extensiontemplate.

```
<ng-template>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="extensiontemplate; context: rowData"></ng-container>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #extensiontemplate> 
<!-- here rowData is undefined -->
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a variable `rowData` in the template like:

```
<ng-template #extensiontemplate let-rowdata> 
    <!-- here rowData is undefined -->
</ng-template>
```

This will work, if your have added an `$implicit` property in the context(rowData), for example, your `rowData` is like:

```
rowData = {$implicit: 'row data'};
```

If you haven't added an implicit property then you need to have a variable with its value as the key in the context.

For example, if your context is

```
rowData = {somethingElse: 'row data'};
```

The you need to have your template like:

```
<ng-template #extensiontemplate let-rowData="somethingElse"> 
    <!-- here rowData is undefined -->
</ng-template>
```

See this documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet

**Edit**

For your case, the retrieved `rowData` which you are passing into another template doesn't have any `$implicit` value, you need to assign it explicitily, do it like:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="extensiontemplate; context: rowData"></ng-container>
<ng-template let-viewDetails="vin" #extensiontemplate>
    <tr *ngIf="viewDetails">
        <td colspan="3">
            Additional row data here for VIN ID: {{viewDetails}}                  
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Check it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bmq2xi?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: What if rowData is not defined in the typescript but only in the html?

Comment: @MarcoMenardi How do you define it in HTML?

Comment: rowData is defined by the primeNG library i'm using.
Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzu7rt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html